# Adding 260 marker locations in Google Maps Android API V2 using arraylist

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am using this code to insert multiple Markers on the google map :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
...

Marker marker1 = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(1.123456, -2.123456))
                .title("Title1")
                .snippet("Snippet1")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon1)));


Marker marker2 = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(3.123456,-4.123456))              
                .title("Title2")
                .snippet("Snippet2")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon2)));
```

But I have a total of 260 markers to add.. each marker with a specific (position,title,snippet,icon).

Can anybody let me know how to use an arraylist and a loop to do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help with understanding java 'for' loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162845/help-with-understanding-java-for-loops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have `ArrayList` with `LatLng` coordinates for your markers. So, you can use it like this, for example:

```
ArrayList<LatLng> coordinates; // your ArrayList with marker's coordinates
BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon2));
...
int size = coordinates.size();  
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    LatLng coordinate = coordinates.get(i);

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
       .position(coordinate)
       .icon(icon)
       .title("Title" + (i + 1))
       .snippet("Snippet" + (i + 1))
       .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f));
}
```

Hope it helps.

**UPD 15.12.2015**

I updated my code code for using all properties, according to your code.

**Another UPD 15.12.2015**

Ok, if we need different titles, snippets, icons and positions for every marker, we need special class for storing this properties, right? It will looks like:

```
public class MyMarker {
    private LatLng position;
    private BitmapDescriptor icon;
    private String title;
    private String snippet;

    public MyMarker(LatLng position, BitmapDescriptor icon, String title, String snippet) {
        this.position = position;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.title = title;
        this.snippet = snippet;
    }

    public LatLng getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public BitmapDescriptor getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getSnippet() {
        return snippet;
    }

    public MarkerOptions buildGoogleMarker() {
        return new MarkerOptions()
           .position(this.position)
           .icon(this.icon)
           .title(this.title)
           .snippet(this.snippet)
           .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f);
    }
}
```

Then, I think, we somehow get collection of such objects. And can use it like this:

```
ArrayList<MyMarker> markers; // your ArrayList with markers
for (MyMarker myMarker: markers) {
    googleMap.addMarker(myMarker.buildGoogleMarker());
}
```

**UPD 3**

To add new item into `ArrayList` use `.add` method of `ArrayList`, e.g:

```
List<MyMarker> markers = new ArrayList<>();
MyMarker myMarker = new MyMarker(
    new LatLng(1.123456, -2.123456), 
    BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon2)),
    "title1",
    "snippet1");
markers.add(myMarker);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but i need tu use all items (position + title + snippet + icon).

Comment: What i need precisely, is to set multiple markers on the map, but every marker has a different (position, title, snippet, icon).

Comment: Thank your for the assistance, Could you give me an example of code to add (position + icon + title + snippet) items to the ArrayList ?

Comment: Ok. Then, mark my code as answer on your question =)