# Could someone explain what this line of code is doing?

Tags: java, arrays, count

I am struggling to come to terms with what this code actually means in simple terms and it appears often and is used often but for some reason it is baffling me as I haven't began to understood it in a simple manner.

```
  for (int i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
     list[i] = 0;
```

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for all the downvotes, genuine question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR It's setting every value that you have in your `list` array to 0.

Looks like you have an integer array `int[] list` that may or may not hold some values. You're using a `for` loop to iterate through every element of your `list` and you're setting each of those values to `0`. It's achieving this by using `i` as the index to set a value of `0` to. It knows to stop by using `list.length`, this means that it will exit the `for` loop when `i` is equal to the number of elements that `list` contains. The `list` array might be used often in different places, so this bit of code would help with cleaning up any unwanted data that `list` might have.
Take a look at [Help with understanding java 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162845/help-with-understanding-java-for-loops) to obtain further knowledge on `for` loops. Take a look at  [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)  to help you understand arrays better.

Comment: Thanks, answered it perfectly.