# One time forloop Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, matrix, iteration

Okay so this is probably a really dumb question but here goes.

I want to run through a matrix to check the values and change them if necessary. I split it in a few parts and one of the parts is checking the above row. 
So say that your rows are 'j' and your columns 'i'. Now I want to keep 'i' constant (=0) and let 'j' run through the amount of rows. The code I used to do this is:

```
 for(int i=0;i<=0;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<worldMatrix[i].length-1;j++) 
        {
              (Do something)
        }
    }
```

I don't have the feeling that the first for loop does anything. But after searching I can't really find an alternative. As I said it is probably really simple and I'm just looking past the solution. I don't know if it is important but I'm trying to program game of life as an exercise.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Well, the outer loop can definitely be removed, and the use of `i` as an array index can be replaced with `0`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help with understanding java 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162845/help-with-understanding-java-for-loops)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep i = 0 then please don't write the first loop only take var i = 0 then written the second loop

```
int i = 0;

for(int j = 1; j < worldMatrix[i].length - 1; j++) {
    //(Do something)
}
```

Comment: `var` doesn't exist in Java.

Answer (score 0):

if *i* is constant and used only here, you can just remove that variable and put number directly.

```
for(int j=1;j<worldMatrix[0].length-1;j++) {
    (Do something)
}
```

Comment: This is probably the best solution I think since i is indeed constant. No I also have a piece of code where I use a forloop with i and j both constant. The problem is that I don't know how to make it run without a forloop. I tried the 'do' statement but it don't seem to get the while to work then.

 for(int i=0;i<=0;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<=0;j++) 
            {
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int j = 0; j<matrix[0].length; j++) {
        // do something
    }
```

or

```
Arrays.stream(matrix[0])
            .forEach(value -> {
                // do something
            });
```

Comment: Could you please provide explanations? It could makes your answer more useful.

Answer (score 0):

the first loop isn't do anything because I isn't changing. the i++ essentially does nothing because the range is 0 to 0.
keep the second loop-

```
 for(int j=1;j<worldMatrix[0].length-1;j++) 
        {
          //action
          System.out.println(j);
          System.out.println(worldMatrix[0]);
          //you can also change the variable in your matrix

        }
```