# How to insert new value in excel sheet for each execution using java?

Tags: java, excel

i would appreciate help to find how to insert new data in excel file but it should add new value in a new row each time i run the java code.

i need to modify this lines:

```
 Row row1 = sheet1.createRow(0);//
 Cell cell1 = row1.createCell(0); //
 cell1.setCellValue("4,0");// the value will be a variable
```

I don't know how to use the for loop here.

```
Workbook readWorkbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("c:\\temp\\update2.xls"));

Sheet sheet = readWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);

Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
System.out.println(cell.toString());

Workbook writeWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet1 = writeWorkbook.createSheet("new sheet");

Row row1 = sheet1.createRow(0);
Cell cell1 = row1.createCell(0);
cell1.setCellValue("4,0");

FileOutputStream fileOut = new
FileOutputStream("c:\\temp\\update2.xls");
writeWorkbook.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

Comment: A loop is a very basic construct in any programming language. If you don't know how to loop over a bunch of rows, I would suggest you to try to understand the concept of looping (which means: a repeated execution of the same statements) by reading some tutorials or examples at first without excel and then apply this concept to your example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help with understanding java 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162845/help-with-understanding-java-for-loops)

Comment: i really don't know how to thank you.

Comment: Sorry if the comment sounded arrogant, but I think it works best if your really try yourself - _learning by doing_!. Open your favorite java IDE, create a simple console app and try to write a `for` loop: write out five lines to the console. Then take this construct and try to modify it to write out five excel rows. Or, if I misread or misunderstood your question, feel free to edit your question and add the code which you tried (and wich didn't work) so that the readers of your question can understand where the problem is.