# trying to print and addition plus variable readen before but the pinting only shows the basic addition variable

Tags: java

In the code part you see there is a variable named "Sumar" which is a basic addition and it's meant to make the addition plus the value given to N in the reading method

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Suma {

    static int n = 0;

    public static void leerN() 
    {
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el valor de 'n'"); 
    }
    public static void resSum(){
        int sumar = 1+2+3+4+5+(n);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "el valor de la suma es igual a:\n"+sumar); 
        }
}
```

[Reading]The reading method reads the number 5[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6xHF.png)

[Result]But the result shows 5 which comes being the result of the addition withouth the value of N, I've tried changing many things and sitll don't get it to add the value of n when showing the result[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmY9l.png)

Comment: Please add your code to the post and not by a likn to an image of the screen.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to get the sum of N plus the sum of all numbers from 1->N, if so you could try using a loop since N could be any number not only 5

Comment: The result doesn't show 5. It shows 15. And the result is correct because n is 0, and 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 0 is equal to 15. Displaying "enter the value of N" in a JOptionPane isn't sufficient to actually change the value of n. You need to add the code to do that: `n = <the entered value>`. JOptionPane's javadoc explains how to get the value entered by the user. Read it.

Comment: @JoshW. Can you show me how could I? I mean, the function "leerN" reads the value for n and in "sumarN" it takes the value of n and puts it in the addition like if it was another number

Comment: No, the method leerN does not read the value for n. It asks the user to enter the value of n, and doesn't do anything with what the user entered. showInputDialog() **returns** what the user enters. And your method completely ignores what is returned.

Comment: @JBNizet So could you please tell me how to make it properly? I'm new to java

Comment: I said it already. You read the JOptionPane javadoc. And you don't ignore what JOptionPane.showInputDialog() returns, because that's precisely what the user has entered in the dialog box. If you don't know what it mans for a method to return something, then take a step back, and re-read your introductory book about methods/functions.

Answer (score 0):

use a loop,
you could use the Scanner by importing the Scanner class at the beginning of the program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public static void resSum()
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); // creating a Scanner obj for getting input
    int input = scan.nextInt(); // getting input from user
    n = input;
    int sumar = 0;
    for(int i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++)
    {
        sumer += i;
    }
    System.out.print("el valor de la suma es igual a:\n"+sumar); // using the print method to print to console. 
}
```

see more about loops in here: [Help with understanding java 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162845/help-with-understanding-java-for-loops)

Comment: edited answer, it should work I think for what your are trying to do.