# How do I count from a specific index in an array on downwards in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, search, count

if I have an array.

```
int [] arr = new int []{1,2,3,4};
```

How do I count from 3 onwards to 1?

More general: How do I count from a specific index in an array on down/upwards?

Comment: `int[] arr = {1,2,3,4};` will also work just fine.

Comment: This is a very basic programming question and can be implemented in many language with a For loop. Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162845/help-with-understanding-java-for-loops

Answer (score 2):

Arrays start at index 0, not 1.

There are many ways to loop over items in an array.  Here is the basic way.

```
int [] arr = new int []{1,2,3,4}; 

// going forward
for (int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    System.out.println(arr[x]);
}

// going backward
for (int x = arr.length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
    System.out.println(arr[x]);
}
```

Comment: look closely. I initialised the first index 0 with number 1.

Answer (score 0):

Using streams (Java 8+) you can have something like:

```
    import java.util.stream.IntStream;

    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[]{1,2,3,3,4};
        int from = 0;
        int to = arr.length;
        IntStream.range(from, to)
                .map(i -> to - i + from - 1)
                .forEach(i -> System.out.println(arr[i]));
    }
}
```